# EF6 Contains() works with only interned Strings

Tags: mysql, entity-framework, contains

I want to filter my entity by name property. I use Contains() method. When I pass parameter as "E" it works but if I pass as variable it doesn't work.

Code is below :

```
if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(searchingModel.LanguageNameContains))
            query = query.Where(n => n.Name.Contains(searchingModel.LanguageNameContains));

        if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(searchingModel.LanguageCodeContains))
            query = query.Where(n => n.Code.Contains(searchingModel.LanguageCodeContains));

        return query;
```

Above example doesn't work. But if I write like this

```
if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(searchingModel.LanguageNameContains))
            query = query.Where(n => n.Name.Contains("E"));

        if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(searchingModel.LanguageCodeContains))
            query = query.Where(n => n.Code.Contains("En"));

        return query;
```

It works. I have debugged lots of times. I passed same parameters as variable and as constants. If I pass as constant it works but If I pass as variable it doesn't work. Curiously enough, The same code works MySql.Data.Entity 6.9.3 but now I am using 6.9.5 and it doesn't work. Is it a bug or my mistake ?

Generated SQL :
-when I pass parameter as variable:

SELECT
`Extent1`.`Id`, 
`Extent1`.`Code`, 
`Extent1`.`Name`
FROM `Languages` AS `Extent1`
 WHERE `Extent1`.`Name` LIKE '%p__linq__0%'

-- p__linq__0: 'E' (Type = String, Size = 1)

-- Executing at 30.12.2014 22:30:40 +02:00

-- Completed in 0 ms with result: EFMySqlDataReader

when I pass as interned string :

SELECT
`Extent1`.`Id`, 
`Extent1`.`Code`, 
`Extent1`.`Name`
FROM `Languages` AS `Extent1`
 WHERE `Extent1`.`Name` LIKE '%E%'

Second one returns rows but first one doesn't return any rows.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean with "doesn't work"? Are you getting an exception?

Comment: I mean nothing retrieving from database. For example there is a row in db let's row's LanguageName = "English" and I am using .Contains(str) and str = "E". In this case, it must bring the row but it brings nothing. But if I pass "E" to method like this .Contains("E") then it brings the row

Comment: Always check the generated SQL.

Comment: I have added generated sql to question.

Comment: Unfortunately not. The issue still exists.